# In Ssrs 2019, how are TaskMask and RoleFlags to be interpreted?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2019

If you do `SELECT * FROM Roles WHERE 1=1;` in the Ssrs database catalog, you see stuff like this:

[image: Output in SSMS of the above SELECT]

How does one interpret the values in "TaskMask" and "RoleFlags"? I've found partial information here and there across the 'Net, but nothing from Microsoft.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing really easily discoverable out there on the 'Net, so I went and decompiled the ReportingServicesLibrary.dll (I used "[dnSpy](https://github.com/0xd4d/dnSpy)") and searched until I found what I was looking for in the Microsoft.ReportingServices.Library.AuthzData class.

I discovered the following about the "Roles" table in the Ssrs database catalog:

1. The values stored in `Roles.RoleFlags` are actually just underlying values of the `SecurityScope` enum. They indicate which enum to use to interpret `TaskMask`.
2. The values stored in `Roles.TaskMask` correspond to the members of either the `CatalogItemTaskEnum`, `CatalogTaskEnum`, or `ModelItemTaskEnum` enums. A "1" means the member/setting is "on" and "0" means it's "off. Reading the string from left-to-right, each position (0-based) corresponds to the enum member's underlying value. If a position is missing on the right end, it's assumed that the setting is "off".

## Warning

If you are going to use Sql to change a Role's TaskMask, don't UPDATE it directly. Instead, use the `SetRolePropertiesAndInvalidatePolicies` sproc. That takes care of setting the `SecData.NtSecDescState` column to 1 on all the existing policies that are linked to the Role (which marks the data as "dirty"). The next time the Ssrs ReportServer service checks for policy updates, it'll update the serialized (`AceCollection`) data stored in the `SecData.NtSecDescPrimary` column for all "dirty" records in that table---for your Authorization Extension. (That `SecData` data is what an Authorization extension is presented with when checking permissions/access.)

## E.g.

Consider the built-in "Folder Viewer" role. Since `RoleFlags` is "0", that corresponds to `SecurityScope.CatalogItem` and means `TaskMask` is interpreted using `CatalogItemTaskEnum`. Next, since `TaskMask` is "000000100000000000", that means the they have the `ViewFolders` "task" permission, because the "1" is at position/index 6 (zero-based) in the `TaskMask` string, and the underlying value of `CatalogItemTaskEnum.ViewFolders` is 6 .

## Code definitions

```cs
internal enum SecurityScope
{
    CatalogItem,
    Catalog,
    ModelItem
}

internal enum CatalogItemTaskEnum
{
    Invalid = 268435455,
    ConfigureAccess = 0,
    CreateLinkedReports,
    ViewReports,
    ManageReports,
    ViewResources,
    ManageResources,
    ViewFolders,
    ManageFolders,
    ManageSnapshots,
    Subscribe,
    ManageAnySubscription,
    ViewDataSources,
    ManageDataSources,
    ViewModels,
    ManageModels,
    ConsumeReports,
    Comment,
    ManageComments
}

internal enum CatalogTaskEnum
{
    Invalid = 268435455,
    ManageRoles = 0,
    ManageSystemSecurity,
    ViewSystemProperties,
    ManageSystemProperties,
    ViewSharedSchedules,
    ManageSharedSchedules,
    GenerateEvents,
    ManageJobs,
    ExecuteReportDefinitions
}

internal enum ModelItemTaskEnum
{
    Invalid = 268435455,
    ViewModelItems = 0
}
```

They've added items over the years. E.g. `CatalogItemTaskEnum.Comment` didn't exist in Ssrs2012.

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Granger answer, here is SQL code that gives each permission separetly.

```
SELECT
    r.*,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 0 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 1), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ConfigureAccess,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 0 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 2), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS CreateLinkedReports,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 0 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 3), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ViewReports,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 0 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 4), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ManageReports,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 0 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 5), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ViewResources,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 0 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 6), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ManageResources,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 0 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 7), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ViewFolders,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 0 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 8), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ManageFolders,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 0 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 9), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ManageSnapshots,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 0 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 10), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS Subscribe,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 0 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 11), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ManageAnySubscription,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 0 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 12), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ViewDataSources,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 0 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 13), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ManageDataSources,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 0 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 14), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ViewModels,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 0 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 15), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ManageModels,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 0 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 16), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ConsumeReports,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 0 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 17), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS Comment,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 0 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 18), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ManageComments,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 1 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 1), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ManageRoles,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 1 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 2), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ManageSystemSecurity,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 1 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 3), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ViewSystemProperties,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 1 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 4), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ManageSystemProperties,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 1 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 5), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ViewSharedSchedules,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 1 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 6), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ManageSharedSchedules,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 1 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 7), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS GenerateEvents,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 1 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 8), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ManageJobs,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 1 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 9), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ExecuteReportDefinitions,
    CAST(IIF(r.RoleFlags = 2 AND RIGHT(LEFT(r.TaskMask + '0', 1), 1) = '1', 1, 0) AS BIT) AS ViewModelItems
FROM dbo.Roles r
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30800592)